# I want to hyperlink two words separately in the footer with no text decoration or underline. Does anybody know the HTML code?

Tags: html, text, hyperlink

I am trying to hyperlink two separate words which sit in either corner in the footer and I don't want any text decoration (underline or changing to blue). However I would like text to turn blue when I hover over.

My code below isn't right and I'm looking for this to be corrected.

Does anybody know the html code for this?

Thank you!!!

```
<head>
<style type="text/css">
.footer {
position: fixed;     
text-align: left;
justify-content: space-between;
display: flex;
bottom: 10px; 
width: 100%;
font-family:Helvetica, sans-serif;
Font-size: 30px;
letter-spacing:0em;
line-height:1.1em;
color:#0000FF;
padding:1em;
}
.footer span a {
color: black;
text-decoration: none;
}
</style>
</head>
<div class="footer">
<span><a href="https://www.blank-site.com/Profile">NAME</span>
<span><a href="https://www.blank-site.com/Work">WORK</span>
</div>
</style></a></a>
```

I want both words 'NAME' (left corner) and 'WORK' (right corner) to link to separate pages and turn blue when you hover over but black when inactive and without the underline.

Comment: What is the error/result you're getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
    <head>
    <style type="text/css">
    .footer {
        position: fixed;     
        text-align: left;
        justify-content: space-between;
        display: flex;
        bottom: 10px; 
        width: 100%;
        font-family:Helvetica, sans-serif;
        Font-size: 30px;
        letter-spacing:0em;
        line-height:1.1em;
        color:#0000FF;
        padding:1em;
        }
    .footer span a {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    }
.footer span a:hover {
    color: blue;
    text-decoration: none;
    }
.footer-item-1{
    float: left; }
.footer-item-2{
    float: right;
      color:black;
      text-decoration: none;}
      .footer-item-2:hover {
        color: blue;
      }
    </style>
    </head>
    <div class="footer">
    <span><a class="footer-item-1" href="https://www.blank-site.com/Profile">NAME</span>
    <span><a class="footer-item-2" href="https://www.blank-site.com/Work">WORK</span>
    </div>
    </style></a></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

We can take NAME and WORK and float them to the left and right.

Also, text-align: left for the footer class would be unnecessary so I'd remove it, unless you are going to add more text to the footer.

And if you aren't planning on adding more hyperlinks to your footer that have color, the selector for span in ".footer span a" is mostly unnecessary.

Also, you have to open and close tags in the correct order and remember to use  and  correctly, this is what would cause the most errors.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
        <title>HTML is not a real language.</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            .footer {
            position: fixed;
            justify-content: space-between;
            display: flex;
            bottom: 10px; 
            width: 100%;
            font-family:Helvetica, sans-serif;
            font-size: 30px;
            letter-spacing:0em;
            line-height:1.1em;
            color:#0000FF;
            padding:1em;
            }
            .name-left {
            float: left;
            }
            .work-right {
            float: right;
            }
            .footer a {
            color: black;
            text-decoration: none;
            }
            .footer a:hover {
            color: blue;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="footer">
            <span class="name-left"><a href="https://www.blank-site.com/Profile">NAME</a></span>
            <span class="work-right"><a href="https://www.blank-site.com/Work">WORK</a></span>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
<!--Tip on Opening and Closing Tags: <p><span>Text</p></span> is incorrect and <p><span>Text</span></p>
would be correct. Also, remember to use <html> and <body> and <style> correctly. (You had a style tag all the way down here.) Please proofread your code. EDIT: Irony 100-->
```